# Is it safe to clear the state after sending its data to Async function?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to build an application that does some aggregations on data, and using timers it sends that aggregations to an asynchronous step that dumps it somewhere else. After the data is sent in the `onTimer` function, I clear the state.

So something like this:

```java
@Override
public void onTimer(long timestamp, KeyedProcessFunction<KEY, IN, Aggregation>.OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Aggregation> out) throws Exception {
    out.collect(new Aggregation(ctx.getCurrentKey(), aggregation.get()));
    aggregation.clear();
}
```

That stream will be passed to an `AsyncDataStream` like this:

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<Aggregation> aggregations;
AsyncDataStream.unorderedWaitWithRetry(aggregations, new AsyncDatabaseRequest(), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 1000, asyncRetryStrategy).addSink(new DiscardingSink<>());
```

Is it safe to clear the state after sending the aggregation to the async step? What happens if it fails to write the data to the destination?

Comment: Since you mention the chance of failure, there are two options:  Leave the data in-memory until the server confirms the correctness of the aggregation, or make the server itself retry on its own until it succeeds. Clearing it right away risks losing data if a failure happens.

Comment: I get that but the operator with state has no knowledge of the async call result that comes after

Comment: Then that's your main issue to fix, make sure the return value comes all the way up to where the data is originally stored.

Answer (score 0):

If the workflow itself fails, then Flink's exactly once mode (assuming you've configured things correctly) will ensure the data isn't dropped. It can mean that a record gets written to the external service more than once, so you'd have to handle that case.

So if a failed write causes the workflow to fail, you should be OK.

If you don't want a write failure to kill/restart the workflow, then it's up to you to figure out how to not drop any data. E.g. you can still generate a result from the async function, but with error information, and then split the stream from the async function into OK & failure streams, and do special processing for the failure stream.